# Multiple commands produce Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode

Multiple commands produce '/Users/Documents/iOS/QuickStartSwift_Demo/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuickStartSwift.app/Frameworks/BytePlusRTC.framework'

Target 'QuickStartSwift' (project 'QuickStartSwift') has copy command from '/Users/Documents/iOS/QuickStartSwift_Demo/Pods/BytePlusRTC/BytePlusRTC.xcframework/ios-x86_64-simulator/BytePlusRTC.framework' to '/Users/Documents/iOS/QuickStartSwift_Demo/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuickStartSwift.app/Frameworks/BytePlusRTC.framework'

That command depends on command in Target 'QuickStartSwift' (project 'QuickStartSwift'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”

I don't see the duplicate in build phrase

I already try to see the duplicate file in build phrase, help me.